Peewe upgrade causing weired autocommit behaviour
We currently use peewe 2.x and this is the code we use custom mysql connection:
from peewee import MySQLDatabase


class SQLDb(MySQLDatabase):
def connect(self, *args, **kwargs):
    attempts = 5
    while attempts > 0:
        # Logic to retry db connection
         
def begin(self):   
    self.execute_sql('set autocommit=0')
     self.execute_sql('begin')
 

Now I call the transaction using
DB.tranaction() while runing the transaction.
Now once we upgraded the peewe to 3.17.x we are seeing weired behaviour.
with this being set as it is
 def begin(self):   
    self.execute_sql('set autocommit=0')
    self.execute_sql('begin')

When txn completes and mysql command run without txn it does not commit the data.
When i remove this line  self.execute_sql('set autocommit=0') it started working as expected.
Now if i remove self.execute_sql('set autocommit=0') i beleive i will be changing transaction behaviour to commit at every mysql command. How do i ensure that with peewe 3.17.x it works as expected?
It works find till peewe 3.15.3. Peewe  3.16 has some breakimng changes related to peewe autocomit behaviour.

The changelog describes the behavior change in 3.16.0: https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/releases/tag/3.16.0
Starting in 3.16.0 we put the database driver into autocommit mode, but balance that with a functional begin() method (so you can presumably drop your override). Transactional semantics are thoroughly tested across Sqlite/MySQL/Postgres and are working properly.
Top-level write queries that are executed outside of a transaction are autocommitted (though this was also the behavior in all previous versions).

Thanks. I found that once we remove the the begin override(). it started working as expected.
Our peewe 2.x begin override code is archaic. I beleive it was put in place because in single transaction we do multiple insert/updates and to make sure during rollback  everything get rolllback.
Just so that I understand once we remove the begin() override.does peewe 3.16 + take care of rolling back in case exception happen in transaction doing multiple operations?

Yes, if you are using the atomic / etc. decorators or context-managers, the rollback will happen on an unhandled exception in the wrapped block.

No, it is not true that enabling autocommit would commit evvery data modification statement separately.
Mysql manual on START TRANSACTION, COMMIT, and ROLLBACK Statements says:

To disable autocommit mode implicitly for a single series of
statements, use the START TRANSACTION statement:


...


With START
TRANSACTION, autocommit remains disabled until you end the transaction
with COMMIT or ROLLBACK.

Start transaction statement is an alias for begin. So, when you start a new transaction explicitly, autocommit is disabled.
